# Intercept responses from WebSocket connection in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, websocket, socket.io, intercept

I have an app which has a UIWebView inside of it with a loaded website. This website has a chart in it which is  periodicly updated with data from remote server via websockets (socket.io).

Im new to websockets technology but Im trying to somehow intercept the chart data that the website is receiving from server via it.

Till now I have managed to catch http requests sent by the website of such address format: “http://website-address/socket.io/?auth_token=...”
I have the socket.io library for iOS but don’t know how to use it to somehow spoof the website connection and acquire the data downloaded by the website. Can anyone help? Is it even possible?

Comment: Here's Socket.io's documentation for Swift and Obj-C - https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

Answer (score 1):

Switch to `WKWebView` if you can. Using javascript bridge is much easier there. That said, with `UIWebView`, you'd need to inject a script that adds a handler for events received by the socket that you are trying to listen to. You can either create an `io` variable by yourself but apparently the server needs auth token. If you cannot create an auth token, you can only do this if you have access to the io variable created by the website.

   Then for adding a handler, you'll need to know what the event name is, that delivers the chart data. You can snoop around the website and see if you can find that. If you cannot all bets are off. Once we register a handler and get the data, we need to pass this back to your native code. This is where `WKWebView` would keep it clean by letting you add message handlers that can deliver messages from js to native code. For `UIWebView` you'll have to create a custom url scheme and spoof a navigation request to pass the data. Lets assume your custom url scheme is 'myApp'. Then the script you'd need to inject would be:

```
<script>
  /* if you can access/create the auth token
   var socket = io('http://website-address/socket.io/?auth_token=');
  */
   var socket = getioReferenceCreatedByWebsite();
   socket.on('<eventName>',function(){
       window.location = 'myApp://<data>';
   };
</script>
```

In your native code:

```
...
webView.delegate = self;
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"<theAboveJSAsAString>"];
....
}
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
   if(request.URL.scheme == @"myApp"){
      NSString *data = request.URL.path;
      //handle the data
      return NO;
   } 
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In regards to Santhosh R answer. I had the problem he mentioned where I could not get a reference to the websocket object as it was caught up in a closure.

I solved this by adding in a preload script which wraps the native Websocket object to store any instantiated websocket objects in an array and then return the newly created websocket object.

Here is the code.

in your WebView element add in a preload attribute.

```
<webview id="myWebview" src="http://exmple.com" preload="./interceptor.js"></webview>
```

and then in inteceptor.js

```
window.NativeWebsocket = WebSocket;
window.WebSocket = function(url, protocols){
    window.interceptedWebsockets = [];
    var ws = new NativeWebsocket(url, protocols);
    interceptedWebsockets.push(ws);
    return ws;
}
```

Then, inside your WebView context you can an access array of instantiated websocket objects using `window.interceptedWebsockets`